# convert column values into a single row by id

Tags: r, tidyr

I want to convert the following dataset :

```
transaction_id productsku
1              SK0001
1              SK0002
2              AB0001
2              AC0001
2              AC0002
3              BC0001
4              BC0002
```

The ideal dataset is:

```
transaction_id x1       x2      x3
1              SK0001   SK0002
2              AB0001   AC0001  AC0002
3              BC0001
4              BC0002
```

So,I use the following code to convert,but it failed.

```
order <- cast(order_0, transaction_id ~ productsku)

Using productsku as value column.  Use the value argument to cast to override this choice
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , variables, drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting based on `transation_id` and then obtaining the `productsku` for each group. Then you can `rbind` the list while subsetting each element of the list to be able to include the element with maximum number of `productsku`.

```
L = lapply(split(df, df$transaction_id), function(a) a$productsku)
max_length = max(lengths(L))
do.call(rbind, lapply(L, function(a) a[1:max_length]))
#  [,1]     [,2]     [,3]    
#1 "SK0001" "SK0002" NA      
#2 "AB0001" "AC0001" "AC0002"
#3 "BC0001" NA       NA      
#4 "BC0002" NA       NA
```

---

**DATA**

```
df = structure(list(transaction_id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L), 
    productsku = c("SK0001", "SK0002", "AB0001", "AC0001", "AC0002", 
    "BC0001", "BC0002")), .Names = c("transaction_id", "productsku"
    ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way. The idea is to combine the variable in the same group and then split them into different columns using `separate`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(transaction_id) %>%
  summarise(product=paste(productsku, collapse=", ")) %>%
  separate(product, c("x1", "x2", "x3"), sep=", ")

# A tibble: 4 × 4
  transaction_id     x1     x2     x3
*          <int>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
1              1 SK0001 SK0002   <NA>
2              2 AB0001 AC0001 AC0002
3              3 BC0001   <NA>   <NA>
4              4 BC0002   <NA>   <NA>
Warning message:
Too few values at 3 locations: 1, 3, 4
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and fast alternative using `data.table` in 2 steps

```
library(data.table)

# convert mydata into a data.table
  setDT(mydata)

# step 1: gather productsku values by transaction id
  temp <- df[, .(product = toString(productsku)), by = list(transaction_id)]

# step 2: separate productsku values in different columns
  temp[, c("x1", "x2", "x3") := tstrsplit(product, ",", fill="")] # you can also use fill=NA

temp
#>    transaction_id                product     x1      x2      x3
#> 1:              1         SK0001, SK0002 SK0001  SK0002        
#> 2:              2 AB0001, AC0001, AC0002 AB0001  AC0001  AC0002
#> 3:              3                 BC0001 BC0001                
#> 4:              4                 BC0002 BC0002
```

another fast alternative using `dcast{data.table}` that gives a slightly different output:

```
# Using dcast
  dcast(df, transaction_id~productsku)

#>    transaction_id AB0001 AC0001 AC0002 BC0001 BC0002 SK0001 SK0002
#> 1:              1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA SK0001 SK0002
#> 2:              2 AB0001 AC0001 AC0002     NA     NA     NA     NA
#> 3:              3     NA     NA     NA BC0001     NA     NA     NA
#> 4:              4     NA     NA     NA     NA BC0002     NA     NA
```